# c++ prefix and postfix expression

Tags: postfix-mta, prefix

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Mybase
{
public:
    Mybase(int value):my_base(value){ }
    Mybase& operator++()
    {
        Mybase tmp(*this);
        ++my_base;
        return tmp;
    }
    Mybase operator++(int)
    {
        ++my_base;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int my_base;
};
```

Prefix expression is correct, or postfix expression is correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Either prefix or postfix can usually be used.  Sometimes it makes a difference, though.  Standard style is to prefer the prefix form, as `++i`, when it does not make a difference.  (This is hard to believe, since there exists a famous language called C++ but none called ++C, but there it is.)

The reason to prefer the prefix form has to do with stack mechanics.  Consider a statement like

```
int n = 2 * (++i - 5);
```

Here, the variable `i` is incremented then used at it stands, its old value immediately forgotten.  Consider by contrast

```
int n = 2 * ((i++) - 5);
```

Here, the value of the variable `i` must be copied as a temporary to the stack, after which `i` is separately incremented.  The processor touches `i` more in this case.

Admittedly, an optimizing compiler might be able to generate equally efficient code in both cases, but the `++i` is inherently cleaner, because the old value of `i` becomes instantly irrelevant, as soon as `i` is updated, after which there is nothing to optimize.  Since there is often no other cause to choose between the two forms, the `++i` is usually preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You got it the other way around.
First operator definition has the signature of the prefix operator but implemented the postfix operator, and the second definition has the signature of postfix but has the body of prefix.
Just swap the body of two methods and they should be fine.